# Request external domain and not care about the response content without using cors or proxy or anything outside of javascript

Tags: javascript

So a couple of days ago i was looking for something like this and had actually found it but never found a use for it. I know its listed somewhere on mozilla's site but i forget what the function is called.

In anycase i wish to request an external domain that doesn't have cors and does not requir external help from things like proxy's. its a rather recent function added to javascript as when i read about it (before i forgot the name) it was listed as expiremental technology. It's supposedly a safe alternative to CORS the only catch is unlike cors you are not allowed to view the response.

What i want to use it for is to basically see if the status code returned is 404 or 200 so i can tell users whether a specific site is having issues and since the ammount of sites that would be requested is huge if i do it server side id prefer to have it done in a clients browser only on specific pages.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could get by with sending a `HEAD` HTTP request.